# Who I have to pay if I make Game/Music/Movie about monkey king (journey to the west)?

Tags: copyright, licensing

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_to_the_West)

> Journey to the West is a Chinese novel published in the 16th century
>   during the Ming dynasty and attributed to Wu Cheng'en.

So I wonder who I will have to pay license if I make Game/Music/Movie about monkey king (journey to the west).

I have tried to search around the internet for similar situations, but I can't find the answer. Similar situations are:

- [Journey to the West: Conquering the Demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_to_the_West:_Conquering_the_Demons)
- [A Chinese Odyssey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Chinese_Odyssey)
- [The Grow 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Grow_2)
- Oriental Legend (an arcade game I played when I was a kid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No one**

There was no such thing as copyright law in 16th century China. Even if there was the product would have long since become public domain - the country with the longest copyright law in the world is MExico at 100 years after the death of the author.

Comment: Thank you very much :) also I found an article about public domain film: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_domain_film